# display load in progess on application page

Tags: application-pages, spgridview

i have an application page called from a webpart with 
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()

On this page i've an spgridview, 2 textbox for choosing date between and a button.
When i click on the button i refresh the grid depending of the date choosed.

I'd like when i click on the button, display "load in progress" till the grid is loaded.
Do you know an easy solution to do this?
(for information i'm already in a modaldialog and i want displaying this wait message inside)

i tried SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose without success because i've an exception on my function that is null or undefined

thanks

Comment: "spgridview, 2 textbox and a button" are they in a visual webpart.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would essentially have 2 ways to my knowledge, after launching a modal window:

- using the SPLongOperation which in result would show the actual
  progress bar and a message at the start, tasks executing or the end, example http://sharepointzen.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/using-splongoperation-for-synchronous-long-running-tasks-in-sharepoint/
- or client side using the same operations UI (via SP.UI.Notify.addNotification method) as SharePoint to show side
  messages when exposing back running operations, such as in
  http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-ui-tip-non-obtrusive-progress-messages/

Comment: thanks for your proposition but for the first one, i don't want to redirect to an other url (just display a loading during th eprocess)
For the second I get Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'ShowWaitMessage': object is null or undefined

Comment: Or you could simply put your GridView within a UpdatePanel which would then enable you to use UpdateProgress controls to handle loading operations.